# WooCommerce Bookings Plugin Not Saving Order ID

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta

I have built a site using WooCommerce Bookings with an AJAX request that processes the payment, creates and order and lastly creates a booking with the order ID.  However, when I send the newly created order ID via the WooCommerce Bookings create method the order doesn't appear in the Booking and I have to manually connect them.

```
$order   = wc_create_order();
$product = wc_get_product($productId);
$price = $product->get_price();
$order->add_product( $product, 1 );
$order->set_total( $price );
update_post_meta($order->id, '_customer_user', get_current_user_id() );
$order->update_status( 'completed' );

$new_booking_data = array(
    'product_id'  => $productId,
    'start_date'  => strtotime($startStr),
    'end_date'    => strtotime($endStr), 
    'user_id'       => $user_ID,
    'order_item_id' => $order->id, // Seems to be an issue here.
    'persons'       => $amountOfPeople,
    'cost'              => $orderTotal, 
    'all_day'           => false,
);

$returnVal = create_wc_booking( $productId, $new_booking_data, 'pending-confirmation', true );
```

I know that the $order->id is valid because I'm able to use it in order to set the customer ID.

Bookings Plugin Reference: (https://docs.woothemes.com/document/creating-bookings-programatically/)

Comment: I tried doing:  `update_post_meta( $bookingId, '_booking_order_id', $order->id );`  It seems a little heavy handed, but it seems to work.  I'll mark this as the answer unless somebody else has a more succinct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor update (I ran into this issue today):

The above solution does not work anymore. The only thing you need to do nowadays is to set the post_parent:

```
wp_update_post(array(

    'ID' => $booking->id,
    'post_parent' => $order->id

));
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by [Gerben Van Dijk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/11150/gerben-van-dijk), we need to update the parent of the order *item*, rather than the order itself.

If there are multiple items in the order - you may require more conditional logic than this, but this will attach the booking to the first item. If there's only one cart item - no problemo! Not an elegant solution - but the built in booking functions work when referring to a booking on my site. For instance, "$booking->get_order_item_id()" did not work later on unless I attached it like this:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
  wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'          => $returnVal->id, // Booking object after success
            'post_parent' => $item->get_id()
        ) );
  break;
}
```